# How can I get itemdata from qcombobox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox

I have a problem when I clicked in a QtWidgets.QPushButton to show the itemData from a QtWidgets.QComboBox. I fill my ComboBox with this code:

```
self.comboBox.addItem("Sandro",1)
self.comboBox.addItem("Daniel",2)
self.comboBox.addItem("Pedro",3)
```

It filled the QtWidgets.QComboBox, however the problem appears when I set the QtWidgets.QPushButton. I added this in the setupUi:

```
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.showId)
```

And finally developed the function showId:

```
id_us = self.comboBox.itemData(self.comboBox.currentIndex())
print('VAL ',id_us)
```

When I clicked my button, the windows closes, What was the problem?
I share all the code of my accessForm.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(598, 245)
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(Form)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 541, 201))
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 150, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 30, 47, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBox)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 30, 111, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
        self.fillCombo()
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.showId)
    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("Form", "Datos"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Inicio"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "TextLabel"))
    def showId(self):
        id_us = self.comboBox.itemData(self.comboBox.currentIndex()).toPyObject()
        print('VAL ',id_us)
    def fillCombo(self):
        self.comboBox.addItem("Sandro",1)
        self.comboBox.addItem("Daniel",2)
        self.comboBox.addItem("Pedro",3)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when I run it in console on Linux then I get `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'toPyObject'`. It works correctly when I remove `.toPyObject()`

Comment: Oh yes. You're ok. I was migrating from PyQt4 and with toPyObject ran. So I did it with your help, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you are using an outdated tutorial, in PyQt4 you had to convert the PyQt object to python native object using the `toPyObject()` method, but in PyQt5 it is no longer necessary:

```
def showId(self):
    id_us = self.comboBox.itemData(self.comboBox.currentIndex()) # .toPyObject()
    print('VAL ',id_us)
```

As a recommendation, it uses the terminal or CMD to obtain the error messages since the IDEs have problems with handling the PyQt error messages.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes I was migrating from pyqt4

Comment: @GSandro_Strongs In PyQt5 are the simplest and readable things since PyQt uses the native types of python